# Get id from button in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have code in script ajax

```
            function paginationData(data) {
            $('#daftarList tbody').empty();
            for(emp in data){
                var empRow = "<tr>";
                empRow += "<td>"+ newDate +"</td>"
                empRow += "<td>"+ data[emp].idnya +"</td>"
                empRow += "<td>"+ data[emp].nama +"</td>"
                empRow += "<td>"+ data[emp].status +"</td>"
                empRow += '<td>
                              <button type="button" name="no_reg" id="'+data[emp].no_reg +'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger updaftar">
                                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></button></td></tr>';
                empRow += "</tr>";
                $('#daftarList tbody').append(empRow);                  
            }
        }



        $(document).on('click', '.updaftar', function(){
         var no_reg = $(this).data("no_reg");
    if(confirm("Your Sure ?"))
    {
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo site_url(); ?>/registrasi/updaftar/",
        method:"POST",
        data:{"no_reg":no_reg},
        error: function (request, error) {
                    console.log(no_reg);
                    alert(" Can't do because: " + error +request);
                },
        success:function(data){
                    console.log(no_reg);
                //createPagination(0);
                alert(no_reg);
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

the problem is when click the button, the data cannot change. the error is undefined no_reg

I've used code

```
document.getElementsByClassName('updaftar')[0].id
```

or

```
document.querySelector('.updaftar').id
```

but it's still a problem undefined no_reg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed somthing here

```
var no_reg = $(this).attr("id");
```